# Using validation on base class variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance, azure

I'm trying to make a form where users can input entities that can be submitted to an azure database. I'd like them to be able to input values that I will use for the `RowKey` and `PartitionKey`. My issue comes in that I know how to add validation to a variable in a model, but I don't know how to add validation to variables of the base class without redefining them.

```
 public class Task : TableEntity
{

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml()]
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml()]
    [StringLength(63, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Must contain only alphanumeric characters and spaces")]
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
```

When I use the code above validation works but instead of setting the base class's `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` it makes new ones (as one might expect) and I'm unable to insert the entity into the database. I'd like to find the syntax for using the base class keys but so far I've had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
public string PartitionKey 
{ 
  get { return base.PartitionKey; } 
  set { base.PartitionKey = value; }
 }
```